How to consider a rapier in AD&D 1ed (PHB/DMG)
The rapier is mentioned neither in the AD&D 1ed PHB nor in the AD&D 1ed DMG. The entry for short sword states "includes all pointed cutting and thrusting weapons with blade length between 15" and 24"." However, the "classic" rapier has a blade significantly longer than two feet. While the scimitar includes an "etc." in its description, it is a curved weapon where the rapier is straight. The long sword's blade is closer in dimension to that of the rapier's, and its weight is similar as well. Would the long sword be the best option for playing a rapier in "pure" AD&D 1ed?
There is plenty of discussion elsewhere on the internet, but that often descends into its characteristics against different armor, which would affect the table on page 38, I reckon.

Are you the DM or are you a players?

I am the player, but I would like to make a case to the DM. If I have to play longsword, I will, but given the backstory I am trying to create, a rapier makes more sense. As I will not be able to use a shield, making the case to the others in the party/NPCs that I ascribe to an "exotic" style would explain why the "man at arms" isn't using the shield with the longsword.

Does your DM use weapon speed and weapon adjustment to-hit vs armor class?

New DM; I’m not sure. I’ve built my character sheet in excel to take that into consideration but I’d appreciate seeing both ways.

Most of this information is found in the sources you have already cited, especially the first Dragonsfoot post.
Valerius' sword of skewering
There is no rapier in the PHB, DMG, or UA in first edition.  The closest you could come would be the sword used by Erol Otus' character Valerius, who is described and statted in the Rogues Gallery.  His sword, seen here and appearing like what might be called a rapier in some times and places, is described as "lightweight and somewhat flimsy-looking".  It "does damage equal to a short sword" but it is a "powerful magic weapon" because it ignores any bonus to armor class of magical armor, and is called the (or a) sword of skewering.
What is it closest to in length
The Wikipedia citation you use for the length of a rapier is between about 40 and 50 inches long, or the height of the navel of the wielder.  As you say, short swords are described in first edition as being between 15 and 24 inches, so clearly shorter than what you would like to call a rapier.  What your analysis is missing is that in first edition terms, a longsword is listed as c. 42 inches and a bastard sword c. 54 inches (PHB 38).
Certainly in length, your rapier is closest to a longsword.  Yet if you consider it significantly lighter, perhaps it should not do as much damage.  But since the base damage of a short sword is d6 and a longsword d8, there is not much difference to split.
Your best option is to port the stats from 2e
Although you are asking for first edition sources, 2E does have stats for a rapier; in both the Complete Fighter's Handbook and the Arms and Equipment Guide.  And since none of the basic swords (bastard, broad, long, short, two-handed) changed their damages or speed factors between 1e and 2e, we can assume that no stats for the 2e rapier would need to be changed when back porting it.  So, for what it's worth, I think "the best option for playing a rapier in "pure" AD&D 1ed" would be to use the 2e stats for the rapier and call it first edition.
In 2e, the rapier does d6+1 damage against small and medium opponents.  This is 1 point more in all aspects (minimum, mean, maximum) than a shortsword.  It is the same mean damage as a longsword, but has a more narrow distribution, with a higher minimum and lower maximum.  All of the other stats (damage vs. size large, weapon speed) are available except for hit adjustment per defender's AC type (since that is not used as such in 2e for individual weapons).  If your DM does not use that optional rule in 1e, the 2e rapier stats will give you everything you need.
